# get back to step 1 in multi-steps form creating by vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, multi-step

I have created a multi-step form by vue.

It works fine when I click next step and previous step buttons.

But I want to let users may get back to step 1, step 2 and step 3 when they are in step 4 (which they can review the information they filled before).

I have tried:

```
toStep1: function() {
            this.step - 4;
        }
```

But it doesn't work.
Do anyone has ideas?

And here is my HTML and vue.js methods:
HTML

```
<section v-show="step === 1">...</section>
<section v-show="step === 2">...</section>
<section v-show="step === 3">...</section>
<section v-show="step === 4">
<button @click.prevent="toStep1">Modify your name</button>
...
</section>

<button class="pre-step" @click.prevent="prevStep" v-if="step != 1">Previous Step</button>

<button class="next-step" @click.prevent="nextStep" v-if="step != totalSteps">Next Step</button>
```

Vue.js

```
methods: {
        prevStep: function() {
            this.step--;
        },
        nextStep: function() {
            this.step++;
        },
        toStep1: function() {
            this.step - 4;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `this.step = this.step - 4;` :)

Comment: assert(4 - 4 !== 1);

Comment: Considering the method name is "toStep1", what about directly using `this.step = 1 `?

Comment: As @Cat mentioned, 4 - 4 = 0. If you want to go back to step 1, then try this.step = 1;

Comment: @HalilÇakar Thank you all so much! Can't imagine this problem bother me a day...